# Search a whole workbook in VBA and then paste findings in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

First off, ill give credit where credit is due. This is put together using code from u/Joe Was from Mr.Excel.com and exceltip.com.

Now that I have gotten that out of the way I am trying to create a search function that will search through my 9 sheet document in excel, to find a value that was typed into a search box. Then paste those values onto the first page of the workbook.

What do I need to change in my code to make it paste to the right place on the search page? I have tried changing things in the last loop because that is where I get the "Run-Time error 91. Object variable or with block variable not set".

I've googled that error, but variables always screw me up so that may be the problem. 
[The search page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzOH3.png)
[This is where the Debugger stops.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftbRI.png)
This is my code so far.

```
Sub Find_one()
'Find Function For ERF Spreadsheet'
'Type in Box, Press Button, Display the Results'
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Found As Range
    Dim myText As String, FirstAddress As String
    Dim AddressStr As String, foundNum As Integer

        myText = Range("D5")

            If myText = "" Then Exit Sub

                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    With ws
                    'Do not search sheet1'
                        If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Then GoTo myNext

                            Set Found = .UsedRange.Find(What:=myText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

                        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
                            FirstAddress = Found.Address

                        Do
                            foundNum = foundNum + 1
                            AddressStr = AddressStr & .Name & " " & Found.Address & vbCrLf

                        Set Found = .UsedRange.FindNext(Found)

                        'Found.EntireRow.Copy _
                        'Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If

myNext:
                    End With

    Next ws

    If Len(AddressStr) Then

            Sheet8.Range("B18") = ws.Cells(x, 1)
            Sheet8.Range("C18") = ws.Cells(x, 2)
            Sheet8.Range("D18") = ws.Cells(x, 3)
            Sheet8.Range("E18") = ws.Cells(x, 4)
            Sheet8.Range("F18") = ws.Cells(x, 5)
            Sheet8.Range("G18") = ws.Cells(x, 6)
            Sheet8.Range("H18") = ws.Cells(x, 7)
            Sheet8.Range("I18") = ws.Cells(x, 8)
            Sheet8.Range("J18") = ws.Cells(x, 9)

    Else:
            MsgBox "Unable to find " & myText & " in this workbook.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the original code for the last loop...

```
If Len(AddressStr) Then

    MsgBox "Found: """ & myText & """ " & foundNum & " times." & vbCr & _
    AddressStr, vbOKOnly, myText & " found in these cells"

Else:

    MsgBox "Unable to find " & myText & " in this workbook.", vbExclamation

End If
```

Comment: If you attempted to attach pictures, it looks like they didn't go through.

Comment: I got it fixed.

Comment: I think a problem is that looking at your attached picture of your workbook, your sheet names are letters and "Search", but you refer to the sheets based on "Sheet1" and "Sheet4". Try replacing those with the actual names of the sheets you're working with, like Worksheets("C") or ws.Name = "Search". Or, if you don't want to use their names, you can do Worksheets(1) or Sheets(4) do reference their location.

Comment: @Dexloft I added a picture of where the debugger stops. The problem is in the last loop. I'm looking for how I could take the string collected by the first loop, and then past that string onto a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this out. I redid how I interpreted the first section. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with everything so let me know if this works or where it went wrong.

```
Sub FindOne()
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim myText As String, searchColumn As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = Sheets(1).Range("D5").Value

    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Equipment Number"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "Sequence Number"
            searchColumn = "B"
        Case "Repair Order Number(s)"
            searchColumn = "D"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
            End Sub
    End Select

    For i = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(i).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            AddressArray(j) = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).Value
        Next j

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            If (InStr(1, AddressArray(j), myText) > 0) Then
                Set nextCell = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A" & j, "I" & j).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Also I have no clue what that second part of the code is supposed to be, so if you want to elaborate on the section with `If Len(AddressStr) Then`, I'd appreciate it because that really doesn't even work as an If...Then statement lol :)

Comment: So it kind of worked.. Right now it only searches A column but it needs to search A-J. I tried to fix it myself but I'm having trouble following your code. Also it needs to past at B18 and not A2. Again, I don't know how to fit that. Then also right now its only giving one instance of what it finds. To kind of explain the project, I have a database of parts spread out across the workbook. I need to create a search page to where anyone can go in and type what they are looking for, and then all of the results will pop up on that first page.

Comment: Also to answer about If Len(AddressStr) Then, I will add to my original post the original code for that area. it may also help you to see what I am looking for this code to do. Originally, it gives you all the locations in a message box. I want the information from those locations to be put in my search results area on the first page.

Comment: Would we be able to change the Search sheet so that someone can go in and say "I have an **Equipment Number** X###" and they search for that? Like an option to choose what value they are searching for? This would make it way faster than searching through every cell in the workbook. I'm imagining a ComboBox with each column header as an option and an empty range (in this case, D5) next to it.

Comment: Also have you tried to do this manually? It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fentz.png) sheet has 9 columns of data but A-J is 10 columns

Comment: Are you thinking something like this? http://imgur.com/a/0CR4v I don't know exactly how it works but if you feel confident in that, I really like the idea. Also, I guess it meant A-I. We don't have to search for the date.

Comment: Check [this](https://prnt.sc/fkm41y) out, a ComboBox is a box where you can choose from a list of values. You can reference its value in VBA with something like ComboBox1.Value or whatever you decide to name it. If you've never used one, there are lots of great websites to help you learn, it's super easy

Comment: I'll give that a try and if I cant figure it out I'll let you know!

Comment: Alright sounds good, I will edit my answer to give you code for the ComboBox, all you have to do is edit the Select Case part to add everything you would want to search by!

Comment: What does the "else" and the "end sub" in the select case area connect to?

Comment: It should trigger if they don't select any value for the combobox and just leave it blank. If you don't like it there, I'd change it to `Case " "`

Comment: Oh and the `End Sub` just Ends the code so that errors don't (or at least shouldn't) pop up

Comment: Wait, I just got an amazing idea for this but I'm not going to be able to explain it very well. If you are comfortable doing so, would you mind emailing the document to me at  iamtommeh@gmail.com? I don't know if I'm even allowed to ask you to do that but this idea is so good

Comment: Yo, it's not letting me reply to your email now, should I send it to a different one? I finished and it works and it is beautiful

Comment: I sent you another email with a different email to try and send it to. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I think I've sent you two now to that email, are you getting them?